# Would this go to 0

Tags: real-analysis

Let $t_{m}$ be the sup of the sum of the pairwise distances
between any $2m$ points in the unit disk. Does $t_{m}/m^{2}$ go to
$0$ as $m\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: I'm puzzled by how you could think this would go to $0$. You are asking whether the average distance between points must go to $0$ when you have more and more of them... of course not.

Comment: I can't even deduce a precise meaning and you already closed the question? Wasn't it better first to be a bit patient to find out what the question really was?

Answer (score 10):

No, it need not go to $0$: just put $m$ points at $(0,-1/2)$ and the other $m$ points at $(0,+1/2)$; the sum of the pairwise distances is $t_m=m^2$, so $t_m/m^2=1$ does not vanish as $m\rightarrow\infty$. More generally, if you distribute the points inside the unit disk with some generic density function, there will be some nonzero average pairwise distance $\bar{t}$, and $t_m/m^2\simeq m(2m-1)\bar{t}/m^2$ will remain nonzero as $m\rightarrow\infty$.